# Embed website into my site

Tags: html, embed

What I am trying to do is embed a website into mine. When you search something on their page their embed site redirects through their pages though it will still be on my web page. Any help will be appreciated. I have partnered up with this site and they don't know how to do it themselves.

I am sorry if this is confusing. Here is a example if it helps

```
<html>//my site
<header>//my site
</header>//my site
<body>//my site
//where embed website is with their page redirects and search engine
</body>//my site
</html>//my site
```

When you search on their site or go to their pages link on their site. This should be like this in way.

```
<html>//my site
<header>//my site
</header>//my site
<body>//my site
//new page on the embed site after redirect
</body>//my site
</html>//my site
```

Any thoughts or places I can go help me figure this out.

Comment: Have a look at [frames](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html) maybe?

Comment: This mdn article [From object to iframe — other embedding technologies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Other_embedding_technologies) might be usefull

Answer (score 51):

You can embed websites into another website using the [`<embed>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed) tag, like so:

```
<embed src="http://www.example.com" style="width:500px; height: 300px;">
```

You can change the height, width, and URL to suit your needs.

The `<embed>` tag is the most up-to-date way to embed websites, as it was introduced with HTML5.

Comment: What's the best way to avoid a fixed size, i.e., to have the embedded website scale responsively to the browser's window size? I'd like to avoid scroll bars within my website.

Comment: Is it possible to set width and height to percentages instead of absolute pixels?

Comment: I don't know @CGFoX... I didn't find a solution after searching for one on the web

Comment: Seems like Emmanuel's answer is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7890207/2745116

Comment: Hey everyone! I know It's been a while now but does anyone know if the embed tag is safe to use as compared with iframe to prevent cross-site scripting and clickjacking?

Comment: embed and i frame not working beacase of SameOrigin xframe

Answer (score 25):

Put content from other site in iframe

```
<iframe src="/othersiteurl" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 6):

You might want to check [HTML frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_%28World_Wide_Web%29), which can do pretty much exactly what you are looking for. They are considered outdated however.

Comment: if frames were outdated 4 years ago already, would it be possible to update this answer with a more recent way of doing this?

Comment: 10 years now, this answer should be removed

Answer (score 4):

**What's the best way to avoid a fixed size, i.e., to have the embedded website scale responsively to the browser's window size? I'd like to avoid scroll bars within my website. – CGFoX Feb 2 '19 at 15:52

**Is it possible to set width and height to percentages instead of absolute pixels? – CGFoX Mar 16 at 11:53

ANSWER: `<embed src="https://YOURDOMAIN.com/PAGE.HTM" style="width:100%; height: 50vw;">`