# Include independent project to the codeigniter view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Is there any possible to include the independent project as a browser in separate catalog/server into codeigniter view?

For example:

```
<?
include 'www.yahoo.com'; 
?>
```

Comment: Would an iframe work?

Comment: Yes could be. So that I would manipulate there :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed website into my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890160/embed-website-into-my-site)

Answer (score 4):

Try including this in your view

```
<iframe class="iframe_element" src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

Be sure to apply style to your `.iframe_element` to make it the size and position that works best for you.