# Embed a Vueitfy user interface into an existing website

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have designed a user interface for a web application using Nuxt.js and Vuetify.js (Nuxt implies the use of Vue.js code)

My interface is quite good, but I need to embed it into an existing website which does not make use of Nuxt/Vuetify stack.

I wonder what are the techniques that could be used in such situations?

I read some old posts like this one: [Embed website into my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890160/embed-website-into-my-site)  but I wonder if there is anything more trend and more suitable for a Vuetify user interface?

Comment: Note that my web user interface has also JavaScript code done in Vue.js

Answer (score 0):

You could take the transpiled, javascript bundle that Webpack creates for your Nuxt/Vuetify application and insert it into whatever webpage would use it. This would let you use the javascript you wrote where you need it on that existing site, but wouldn't use it for any other pages.

If you don't like that approach, however, `<iframe>`s are always an option.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will study later your approach and I may accept your answer if it is good